# how to plot function from multiple points

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, tikz-graphdrawing

Actually wanted to draw and plot Optical and acoustic branch but don't know it 
what's the command to draw a function like this ? 
[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: I wouldl guess that the math refers only to the intersections with the axes, (0-\pi/a ?).  You really don't have enough information here to do anything.  I would overlay some graph paper and start recording points, then graph using smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pgfplots can produce such plots.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
 omegaplus(\k,\K,\a,\mone,\mtwo)=sqrt(\K*(1/\mone+1/\mtwo)+
 \K*sqrt((1/\mone+1/\mtwo)^2-4*pow(sin(\k*\a/2),2)/(\mone*\mtwo)));
 omegaminus(\k,\K,\a,\mone,\mtwo)=sqrt(\K*(1/\mone+1/\mtwo)-
 \K*sqrt((1/\mone+1/\mtwo)^2-4*pow(sin(\k*\a/2),2)/(\mone*\mtwo)));}]
  \begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom,axis y line=middle,trig format=rad,
    xlabel={$k$},xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ymax=2,xmax=3.5,clip=false,
    xticklabels={},yticklabels={},trig format=rad]
    \addplot[color=red,domain=0:pi,smooth,samples=51] {omegaplus(x,1,1,1,2)}
    node[pos=0,left,black]{$\displaystyle2C\left(\frac{1}{m_1}+\frac{1}{m_2}\right)^{1/2}$}
    node[pos=1,right,black]{$\displaystyle\left(\frac{2C}{m_1}\right)^{1/2}$}
    node[midway,above,sloped,font=\sffamily]{optical branch};
    \addplot[color=blue,domain=0:pi,smooth,samples=51] {omegaminus(x,1,1,1,2)}
    node[pos=1,right,black]{$\displaystyle\left(\frac{2C}{m_2}\right)^{1/2}$}
    node[midway,above,sloped,font=\sffamily]{acoustic branch};
   \draw[thick] (pi,0)  -- (pi,2);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot , could you explain what you've done here by declaring the function and how do you put "acoustic branch" and "optical branch" in exact proper position.

Comment: @Quintis (I see this comment only now, sometimes comments get swallowed by the system.) All I did was to punch in the dispersion relations for phonons, which can be found e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon). And then you can position stuff with `pos=<f>` where `f=0` is the start and `f=1` the end of the plot.